# Android TextView gets cut off on right side of screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

The date TextView in the following xml gets cut off on the right side of the screen. How can I fix this?

Also I'm not sure if I'm doing this right, but the encrypted and signed ImageViews will never appear together at the same time, it will be either or.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/date_container"
                android:layout_width="80dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/date_margin_top"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/encrypted"
                    android:layout_width="36dip"
                    android:layout_height="16dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src="@drawable/badge_encrypted" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/signed"
                    android:layout_width="36dip"
                    android:layout_height="16dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src="@drawable/badge_signed" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/paperclip"
                    android:layout_width="36dip"
                    android:layout_height="16 dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_attachment" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/date_font_size"
                    android:text="@string/long_string"
                    android:lines="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of setting fixed width, you could set width to match_parent and add Layout_weight:

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_container"
            android:layout_width="80dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/date_margin_top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/encrypted"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="16dip"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/badge_encrypted" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/signed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/badge_signed" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/paperclip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="16dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_badge_attachment" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/date_font_size"
                android:text="@string/long_string"
                android:lines="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

But this depends on what You want. Usualy, you have to define different layout resource for multiple screen support. With this example, you also have to set scaleType for every imageView, to scale every resource the right way.